# 3DS Max model won't appear in Blitz3D

Tags: blitz3d

First post, yay, I guess. I'm new to Blitz3D, so I'm just now learning how to import a model from 3DS Max into Blitz. Here's the code:

```
Graphics3D 640,480,32,2
SetBuffer BackBuffer()

camera = CreateCamera()

light = CreateLight()

bottle = LoadMesh("bottle.3DS")
ScaleEntity bottle,0.1,0.1,0.1


End
```

I put the model file and the code in a folder together, but there's just black when I compile and run the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since ScaleEntity isn't giving you an error, the model does seem to load. However, entities are created at 0, 0, 0 by default, so chances are you just can't see the bottle because your camera is inside it. Try something along the lines of `PositionEntity camera, 0, 0, -5` and see if that helps.

Also, if that is your entire code, you're missing a `RenderWorld` and `Flip`; either within a loop, or followed by something like `WaitKey`, so that you can see what's being displayed before your program closes.